# Autoresize container height created from nib if subview (UILabel) height changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uilabel

I want to resize container view (in my case `AnnotationCallOut`) when the text in `UIlabel` (named `textLabel`) becomes too large.
Container view has defined height and width (`size: Freeform, width:200, height: 100`).
In this picture you can see that I have created constraints between elements:
[image: Container view with two labels]

But when I add a large text into `textLabel`, it simply goes over:
[image: Text goes out of container view]
  How to autoresize container view in this case?
Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you use textView and set its width and height constraint that way even if txt is big you can scroll and see problem with label is that it will either show everything or if you restrict its height it will truncate the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a bottom constraint between the frame and the bottom label, without this the autolayout doesn't know what to do with the height of the frame!

Comment: No, the same result after adding constraint Superview.Bottom = TextLabel.Bottom :(

Comment: Are you forcing the layout to update when the textLabel expands?

Comment: Works when adding self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; but then i can't use view.center property

Comment: Layout constraints are supposed to be used with self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO. Maybe you should review your view.center property and how you are using it.  You haven't supplied any code so no one can help with that part.

Answer (score 0):

Add the constraints, titleLabel set Top, Left, Right and fixed height constraints example is given below,

[image]

then SecondLabel set the Top, Left, Right, Bottom constraints to be set, if you will get exact output.

[image]

hope its helpful